# Is there any way to add geometry to an object according to the "outline" of texture?

Tags: uv, add-on, vertices, geometry

This is probably wishful thinking, but is it possible to add extra vertices to follow the texture of the object, without adding them manually with Knife or something similar?

For example, this Mario mushroom's geometry doesn't "outline" the white circles on the texture

[image]
[image]

I couldn't find an addon that does this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way. In deep history of 2.49, there was a great script of Pildanovak (Fracture) and one of the feature was image used to split object onto a parts according image lines.

Current Blender has only feature for Images added as Empty object. Search for *Trace Image to Grease Pencil* ... but as you can see works only for a Plane.

In this specific situation you can probably add a Cube. Join with your mesh. In Edit mode select Cube and search for **Intersect** operator  which cuts Sphere (add edges) in place of Cube faces intersects ...

[image]

... Delete Cube.

[image]

Note ... I don't think you would be happy with result in any case (even it will work as you asked for) ... topology would be very bad.